# Forward Nagios server state to a second server

Tags: nagios, forwarding

Is there a way to forward the state of a Nagios server to a second Nagios server?

I want to install a Nagios server which does the usual collecting of information about the machines and services on the network. This one should run in the local network, with unlimited access to the other machines.

For the times when i'm not in the office, i would like to look at the Nagios state, with the web interface. But i don't want to allow connections from the outside to the local network.

My idea is to have a second Nagios server, which is located outside of the office network (maybe in a DMZ), and that the main server sends his results of the checks to the outside server. This way there would be only an outgoing connection from the local network. The web access goes to the outside server.

Is this possible with Nagios, or is another nice solution?

Comment: Are you talking about the checks or just the UI? Either can be forwarded. You can also look at check_mk for this to be semi-automated http://mathias-kettner.com/check_mk.html

Comment: Checks should run on the machine in the local network (not visible from outside), and the results should be forwarded to the machine outside of this network, which offers the web interface ans is accessible from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking about is basically the classic [distributed](http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs25en/distributed.html) or [failover monitoring](http://nagios.manubulon.com/traduction/docs25en/redundancy.html) setup. (These docs are from 2.x, but the idea is the same.)

(Unfortunately, the old "redundant and failover monitoring" docs [appear to be gone](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/redundancy.html), replaced instead with solutions for Nagios XI.)

The idea is to have one Nagios instance forward all of its check results to another server. You used to do this with an [ocsp_command](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html#ocsp_command) (and/or ochp_command) that would forward all check results to another server.

The problem is that all of the hosts and services also have to be defined on the receiving end (as passive checks). This can be mitigated with config management tools.

There are several more-modern options available now, like DNX and MNTOS, which are detailed in the [new distributed monitoring docs](https://library.nagios.com/library/products/nagiosxi/documentation/385-distributed-monitoring-solutions-for-nagios). I refer you to the classic docs because these new tools might not work for you if you absolutely cannot have inbound traffic (for job submission).